# Tensorflow running on terminal but not with my code editor

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, keras, visual-studio-code

I have created a venv and installed the tenserflow via pip, checked the versions and everything seems fine. However, when I want to run my code (simply **import **tensor**flow**) it pops the following error.

```
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'**
```

I can't use Keras as well because of that.
Something also caught my attention, when on terminal and venv active I run the same code on python3 and it does just fine. I am able to import Keras as well on terminal Python3.

What could be my problem? I have read almost every article and tried every possible solutions that can be found on the web.

System: MACOS Mojave
Python: 3.8.8
Pip: the latest
Code editor: Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, please refer to the following:

1. The location where the module is installed is not the python environment currently used by VS Code.

   Please use "`pip --version`" in the VS Code terminal to check whether the source of the module installation tool "pip" is the same as that shown in the lower left corner of VS Code.

   (If they are different, please use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new VS Code terminal, it will automatically enter the selected environment.)
2. Related files in the installation package of the module are damaged.

   Please uninstall the module "tensorflow" and reinstall it. (`pip uninstall tensorflow` `pip install tensorflow`)
3. Please check the naming of the module installation package. (Please pay attention to the case of naming.)

   [image]

Reference: [Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest. I think the problem is with the interpreter. I found out that when I followed your first suggestion. However, I can't select a new interpreter under my bin folder inside the current venv env. It's a shortcut to a global one. Could it be the problem itself? I'm sure it's not #2 or #3, I guess VS Code is not running on the same env where my modules are

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I closed my other workspace, restarted my VS code selecting another workspace. Changed the interpreter on my venv. and boom, the result. Thank you fro your guidance @JillCheng

Answer (score 0):

1. You loaded the venv in visual studio code?
2. Reinstall the package using pip3 in the vscode command line.
3. If these dont work theres not much i could say to help except, anaconda for virtual env works really well woth vscode and would probably fix it.

Comment: Yes, I run my code on venv and I tried vscode command line as well. Unfortunately didn't work. Thanks for suggestions though